# Updating Rows Into Different Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Both of these tables already exist, so not looking for a dynamic situation. The goal is to consolidate the data rows horizontally, but have them to the leftmost "data" field available. There will never be a 4th entry.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Table1:

```
ID|Data
--------
A | 1
A | 2
B | 3
C | 4
C | 5
C | 6
```

Table2:

```
ID | Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3
------------------------------
A  |        |        |
B  |        |        |
C  |        |        |
```

Desired Result of Table2:

```
ID | Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3
------------------------------
A  |   1    |   2    |
B  |   3    |        |
C  |   6    |   7    |   8
```

Comment: Why do you want to store the data in this format? Typically you'd show it in that format for presentation but not store it that way.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number`:

```
select id,
    max(case when rn = 1 then data end) as data_1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then data end) as data_2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then data end) as data_3
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over (
            partition by id order by data
            ) as rn
    from your_table t
    ) t
group by id;
```